# Mudar cor do ícone apos clicar ou hover input

Tags: html, css, html5

Gostaria de assim que eu clica no input mudar a cor do meu icone

Meu form

```
<form method="post" id="form">

<div class="input-wrapper">
<div class="icone icone-user"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" id="usuario"  name="usuario"/>
</div>

....
</form>
```

já tentei algo como

```
input.icone {
color:red;
}

input.icone:active , input.icone:focus {
color:red;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu ícone é uma imagem tipo um PNG ou GIF? Ou é um SVG? Ou é algum framework de Fonts tipo FontAwesome ou Glyphicons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse exemplo simples estou trocando a imagem quando vc seleciona o `input`. Com essa técnica vc pode alternar entre duas imagens uma cinza e outra vermelha.

O macete aqui é usar o seletor irmão **`+`** e colocar a `div` depois do `input`, assim quando vc selecionar o `input` ele pega o irmão que é a `div` dessa forma `.input-wrapper input:focus + div { ... }`

OBS: Aqui eu fiz trocando a imagem, então tem um "delay" entre a troca pq tem que baixar a outra imagem e depois exibi-la. O mais correto aqui seria usar `background-position` e fazr uma troca de posição no estilo `sprite` para evitar esse *lag*. [Aqui tem um link bem didático sobre Sprites](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Para entender melhor veja abaixo o exemplo funcionando.

```css
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.input-wrapper input {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3.25em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 2rem;
}
.input-wrapper input:focus, .input-wrapper input:active{
    border-color:red;
}
.icone {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5rem;
    top: 0.16em;
    width: 2em;
    height: 1.5em;
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/16/16);
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 100;
}
.input-wrapper input:focus + div, .input-wrapper input:active + div {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/16/16);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" id="usuario"  name="usuario"/>
        <div class="icone icone-user"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: deu certo, mt obrigado

Comment: @JavaScript que bom que deu certo ai. Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente

```
.icone:before { color:red; }
```

ou

```
.icone-user:before { color:red; }
```

De qualquer forma, só inspecionando o código, consigo dar uma resposta mais concreta.

Comment: ficou red antes mesmo de clicar, gostaria de fica somente quando clica no input